# Change width if text in input is not empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, width

I want to make the width of an input field 100% if there is some text present in it.
I tried the below jquery commands but had no luck.

```
$("#field").change(function(){
      if($(this).val() != '')
      {
         $(this).css("width",100%);
      }
  });

$('#field').on('change', function() { 
     if($(this).val()!='')
     {
             $(this).css("width",100%);
     }
    });
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest any alternate approaches?

Comment: Show you html. The parent container you are using may have an effect on what is considered 100% width.

Comment: Secondly, is 100% an typo? It should be a string "100%"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that the "change" event fires after the focus has been lost by the element, right? Use the `input` event if you want the change immediately.

Also, `100%` needs to be in quotes as this is the actual value you wish to use.

```js
// the change event triggers after the focus is lost on the element
$('#field').on('change', function() { 
     if($(this).val()!=='')     {
             $(this).css("width","100%");
     }
});

// The input event fires as the value changes
$('#field2').on('input', function() { 
     if($(this).val()!=='')     {
             $(this).css("width","100%");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<input id="field" placeholder="type and then hit TAB">
</div>

<div>
<input id="field2" placeholder="just type">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to set a string as value for the width attribute

like:

```
$(this).css("width","100%");
```

otherwise js will interpret `%` as modulus operator not as a unit

Answer (score 1):

because 100% not a number.this is string;

```js
$('#field').on('input', function() {
     if($(this).val() != '')
     {
             $(this).css("width","100%");
     }else{
       $(this).css("width","20%");
     }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field">
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you have a typo, change `100%` to `"100%"`. And if you want immediate change use `on keypress` or better yet `on input`:

```js
$('#field').on('input', function() {
  if ($(this).val() != '') {
    $(this).css("width", "100%");
  }else{
    $(this).css("width", "50%");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="field" style="width:50%;" />
```

Comment: `keypress` won't work in all situations. `input` is the best choice.